# How to collect values from Json by key

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion

Thanks in prior for advising. I have the following JSON I retrieve from a REST Service.

```
    "events": [
        {
        "id": 408,
        "name": "My Test1",
        "modulename": "test",
        "instance": 0,
        "timestart": 1470370500,
        "timeduration": 864000,

        },
        {
        "id": 418,
        "name": "Quiz Open",
        "modulename": "quiz",
        "instance": 225,
        "timestart": 1473737880,
        "timeduration": 0,
        },
        {
        "id": 423,
        "name": "Quiz Close",
        "modulename": "quiz",
        "instance": 225,
        "timestart": 1476665040,
        "timeduration": 0,
        },
        {
        "id": 409,
        "name": "August event",
        "modulename": "event",
        "instance": 0,
        "timestart": 1467295200,
        "timeduration": 2474700,
        }
    ]
```

I need to read the JSON and output in the following JSON format

```
"output": [   
    {
       "name": 
        "Start":
        "End":
    }

]
```

My question comes in the point of the name as "Quiz" which is the "modulename" in the JSON input. The Quiz opens at a date (timestart) with modulename as "quiz" and "instance" - 225 as the unique identifier and ends at a different date ( timestart ) with the same instance id. The json contains 100s of events in one big array. My "End" in output json object is the "timestart" + "timeduration".

My Question is what is the effective algorithm to iterate if the module name is "quiz" get the instance and loop through the whole array to find the next occurence of the instance and add to the output json. Any pointers ?

Comment: Read the json using `json_decode()`, retrieve the desire data and calculate the end time also insert into a new array and make `json_encode()` as you want back to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first make sure that your json is in right format if your json is like that:-

```
$str='{"events": [
    {
    "id": 408,
    "name": "My Test1",
    "modulename": "test",
    "instance": 0,
    "timestart": 1470370500,
    "timeduration": 864000
    },
    {
    "id": 418,
    "name": "Quiz Open",
    "modulename": "quiz",
    "instance": 225,
    "timestart": 1473737880,
    "timeduration": 0
    },
    {
    "id": 423,
    "name": "Quiz Close",
    "modulename": "quiz",
    "instance": 225,
    "timestart": 1476665040,
    "timeduration": 0
    },
    {
    "id": 409,
    "name": "August event",
    "modulename": "event",
    "instance": 0,
    "timestart": 1467295200,
    "timeduration": 2474700
    }
]}';
```

Then you can do this....`

```
$arr=json_decode($str,true);
$result=array();
$prevInstance=array();
foreach($arr['events'] as $key=>$val){
if($val['modulename']=='quiz' && array_key_exists($val['instance'],    $prevInstance)){
$k= $prevInstance[$val['instance']];
$result['output'][$k]['End']=$val['timestart']; 
}else{
$tmp['name']=$val['name'];
$tmp['Start']=$val['timestart'];
$tmp['End']=$val['timeduration'];
$result['output'][$val['id']]=$tmp;     
}
$prevInstance[$val['instance']]=$val['id'];;
}
$data=array();
foreach ($result['output'] as $ret){
$data['output'][]=$ret;
}
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Pradyut .. I tried with your implementation and got back 

   `"output": [
     {
    "name": "Quiz Open",
    "Start": 1473737880,
    "End": 0
   }, {
    "name": "Quiz with a duration for attempt (Quiz closes)",
    "Start": 1476665040,
    "End": 0
   }, {
    "name": "Quiz Future (Quiz closes)",
    "Start": 1476681300,
    "End": 0
   }, {
    "name": "Quiz Future (Quiz opens)",
    "Start": 1476162900,
    "End": 0
   }
   ]`

Comment: what I am in my mind for my output json is 

   `"output": [
     {
    "name": "Quiz Open",
    "Start": 1473737880,
    "End": 1476665040 
   }
   {
    "name": "MyTest1",
    "Start": 1470370500,
    "End": 864000
   }, {
    "name": "August event",
    "Start": 1476162900,
    "End": 2474700
   }
   ]`

Comment: The condition is, if Modulename = "quiz" and "instance" ( in this case 225 ) matches the timestart of the second event is the "End" field. in the first event "quiz open" case, the "Start" is the "timestart" of "quiz open" and "end" is the "timestart of "Quiz close". And, if the module name is not matching "quiz" like "MyTest1" and "August Event" are to be displayed as it is. I didnt thought it is going to be this complex :-(

Comment: Please replace my previous code with this:-$arr=json_decode($str,true);
$result=array();
$prevInstance="";
foreach($arr['events'] as $key=>$val){
 if($val['modulename']=='quiz' && $prevInstance==$val['instance']){
  $k= $key-1;
 $result['output'][$k]['End']=$val['timestart']; 
 }else{
 $tmp['name']=$val['name'];
 $tmp['Start']=$val['timestart'];
 $tmp['End']=$val['timeduration'];
 $result['output'][]=$tmp;
  
 }
 
 $prevInstance=$val['instance'];
}

Comment: Great Stuff, Thanks Pradyut .. Probably the last one I ask, the "quiz close" is not always the next one after "quiz open", some times it can down further .. do you have any clue how to implement in that condition ?

Comment: I have changed a small in code above.it will solve your problem.. Thanks @Kannan

Comment: please let me know whether it is working or not. @Kannan

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($event,true); // first decode your retrieved array 
$output = array();

foreach ($array as $key) { // then loop through it
if ($array[$key]['modulename'] == "quiz") { // only select if modulename is "quiz"
        $obj = array("name" => $array[$key]['name'], "Start" => $array[$key]['timestart'], "END" => ($array[$key]['timestart'] + $array[$key]['timeend']));
        array_push($output, $obj);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

return json_encode($output); // in last for output in JSON, encode the output array

```
//output: [{"name":"quiz","Start":123,"END":579},{"name":"quiz","Start":123,"END":579},{"name":"quiz","Start":123,"END":579}]
```

Comment: There's an error in your foreach because the decoded json will return an `std Class` object not an associative array.

Comment: @aldrin27 you may use the "true" parameter as json_decode($event,true).